# American English, British English, or both?

Tags: discussion, editing

I've always assumed both are acceptable on Stack Exchange, but just had three edit suggestions (all from same user), two of which just changed "optimiser" to "optimizer".

Comment: The user in question is clearly on a rep/badge hunt and has apparently suggested a large amount of spelling and grammar corrections. Some of them seem to be actual improvements, but also some of them change meaning, and many of them are very trivial, which is annoying to see in the edit queue.

Answer (score 6):

Both are fine, as far as I know. The differences are small and make no difference to intelligibility, so should not be 'fixed' in edits. If you post an example maybe we can ping the person who made/approved the edits (hope it wasn't me accidentally)

Comment: Edit suggestions that convert British to American English: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/9522 and http://datascience.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/9519 - the user is making *some* edits with value, but IMO needs to increase their signal to noise.

Comment: Yes, I agree. CC @Rubens

Comment: Same user on an edit binge again, and I find myself rejecting the *same* edits (favor for favour etc). I'm wondering if he/she's scripted something?

Comment: For now roll back the edit to make it clear you don't agree with it. If it keeps going I'll PM the person.